# How to make a nested dictionary from an SqlAlchemy output (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following output from an **SqlAlchemy** `select` operator.

```
| device_id |     event_name      | event_count |
| :--------:| :-----------------: |:-----------:|
| 123456    | speed more than 100 |      3      |
| 123456    | speed less than 12  |      0      |
| 334455    | out of NYC          |      5      |
| 111111    | in UCSD campus      |      1      |
```

Now I want to save this result into a nested dictionary with the following format, and I don't know how to do it efficiently.

I need to have a dictionary in which its keys are the `device_id`s, and the values are dictionaries in which the keys are `event_name`s and the values are `event_count`s.

```
{'123456' : {'speed more than 100' : 3,
             'speed less than 12': 0},
 '334455' : {'out of NYC' : 5},
 '111111' : {'in UCSD campus' : 1}
}
```

Here is my code.

```
 def count_per_event_json(self, count_per_event_query_result):
        result = {}
        print(count_per_event_query_result)
        for item in enumerate(count_per_event_query_result):
            if item[0] not in result.keys():
                # result[item[0]] = {I don't know how to fill this inner dict'}
    
        return result
```

I also calculate the input argument and pass it to the function like this:

```
def count_per_event(self):
    count_per_event_query = select(EventsModel.device_id, EventsModel.event_name,
                                   func.count(EventsModel.rule_table_id)) \
        .where(EventsModel.timestamp <= self.max_utc_timestamp) \
        .where(EventsModel.timestamp >= self.min_utc_timestamp) \
        .group_by(EventsModel.device_id, EventsModel.rule_table_id) \
        .execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")

    return count_per_event_query


async def cube_calculator(self):
     async with async_session() as session:
                count_per_event_query_result = await session.execute(self.count_per_event())
                json = self.count_per_event_json(count_per_event_query_result) # the type of  count_per_event_query is  <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# Use pandas.read_sql to read the query results into a dataframe
df = pd.read_sql(select_query, con=your_db_connection)

# Use the pandas groupby function to group the dataframe by device_id
grouped_df = df.groupby('device_id')

# Convert the grouped dataframe into a nested dictionary using the to_dict method
result_dict = grouped_df.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('event_name')['event_count'].to_dict()).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a way to do it without using `read_sql` function? Because my instructor told me on not to call your database connection and use of the output of

 `await session.executesession(the select query output)`.

And if we had a huge amount of data, won't it be better not to use `pandas` library?

Comment: Depening on what the output format is you could feed it directly to pandas: `df = pd.DataFrame(output_variable)` And pandas is built for large datasets, depending on what you want to do with the data you could opt to keep it in a DataFrame format for faster computation.